# Show custom attribute on Orders Grid in Magento

Tags: magento

I used HWG Attribute Manager to add custom attributes to customers. ie IDNumber.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-attributes-4340.html

So if the customers made an order, in the orders grid in admin, I want to get this attribute. I am having issues doing this. Has anyone tried this before?

The added attributes are in `customer_entity_varchar` in the database.

I tried this,

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));

$this->addColumn('Admin Number', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Admin Number'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was just my mistake.

This will work:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_customer_attribute_name')
```